# How does Javascript's Range Traversal work?

Tags: javascript, dom, range

I'm currently reading into Javascript's createRange() function and related constructs and was thinking about what applications this had.

Then I found out about this application "https://www.warroomlaw.com/demo", it uses a highlighting ability based on mouse clicks and then saves the highlighted data. Very useful for studying or research.

However it's HTML code is based on tables, I was wondering is it actually using createRange() or related functions or is it using something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is using indeed using ranges (and the browser [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection)) to do the highlighting. You could study the code in the demo page HTML from line 822 onwards to work out what it's doing, although it's not a great example because the JavaScript highlight code is very tightly coupled to the particular HTML of the page.

Comment: Given that it's coupled to the table layout, how would you improve it so it could work with any textual content (such as in a p tag or editablecontent)?